# How can I check a page permission in user mode in C?

Tags: c, linux, qemu

I am currently implementing a distributed system and its **Distributed Shared Memory protocol**. It could be easier if I can check the page permission(rwx, stored in pte) of a certain virtual address **in user mode**.

---

**What I want to do:**

Get the pte of a virtual address. So I can check the last 3 bits stored in it representing `PROT_READ`/`PROT_WRITE`/`PROT_NONE`.

---

**What I did:**

1. Tried to use the pmd's self reference to get the pte. Failed.
2. Try other methods. It is dumb to record everything. I've tried it and  it worked but now I want to improve it.

There is no such macros in qemu

```c
407         pgd_t *pgd;
408         pmd_t *pmd;
409         pte_t *ptep, pte;
410 
411         pgd = pgd_offset(mm, address);
412         if (pgd_none(*pgd) || pgd_bad(*pgd))
413                 goto out;
414 
415         pmd = pmd_offset(pgd, address);
416         if (pmd_none(*pmd) || pmd_bad(*pmd))
417                 goto out;
418 
419         ptep = pte_offset(pmd, address);
420         if (!ptep)
421                 goto out;
422 
423         pte = *ptep;
```

So the above code doesn't work for me, not to mention it runs in kernel mode.

There is supposed to be a self reference pmd in pgd, but I think I found the wrong one.

```c
// I found it in qemu/roms/qemu-palcode/init.c
#define PAGE_SHIFT 13
#define VPTPTR 0xfffffffe00000000UL
static inline unsigned long
pt_index(unsigned long addr, int level)
{
    return (addr >> (PAGE_SHIFT + (10 * level))) & 0x3ff;
}
...
static void
init_page_table(void)
{
  /* Install the self-reference for the virtual page table base register.  */
  page_dir[pt_index(VPTPTR, 2)] = build_pte(page_dir);
...
```

I don't understand why the VPTPTR is set to such value and how can I use it?

```c
// fill the 4th page index(47-39) with 1
    unsigned long pgd_index = 0b0000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    unsigned long pg_addr_pte = host_addr |= pgd_index;
```

But it doesn't work, its a invalid address.

---

This can be equal to "get the physical address of a page in linux" since both physical address and page permissions are stored in pte.

Provided a virtual address, check the permission of its page. In user mode.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The source code in qemu/roms is code for various boot ROMs that we ship with QEMU to run as guest code. The particular one you've found is for Alpha, and it is entirely irrelevant here.